# how to add multiple box inside a box

Tags: html, css

i was trying to add multiple box inside another but i am not getting as i want please help!why i am getting line only?i added display and overflow attributes still i am getting so

```
 style.css

 @charset "utf-8";

 body {
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     background:url(../images/back1.png);
     background-repeat:repeat;  
}

.logomainbox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(#FC8E03, #FF9801);
}

.menubar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(#DADADA,#C8C6C6);
}

.imageslide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 275px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(#FC8E03, #FF9801);
}

.textdiscription {
    width: 60%;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left:20%;
    margin-right:20%;
    border:3px solid red;
}
.textare {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue; 
}

.box {
    height: 250px;
    wedith: 30%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:auto;  
}

 index.html
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <title>Home</title>
 </head>


 <body>
  <div class="logomainbox">

 </div>
 <div class="menubar">

  </div>
  <div class="imageslide">

     </div>
  <div class="textdiscription">
  <div class="textare">
  </div>
  <center>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
 <div class="box">
 </div>
 <div class="box">
 </div>
 </center>
 </div>


 </body>
 </html>
```

[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEPjy.png)

[what i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRmuq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a spelling issue,

```
.box
wedith:30%
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have `wedith` instead of `width`. Change your code to:

```
.box {
    height:250px;
    width:30%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:auto;  
}
```

Comment: @NikhilAlex Can I know why you reject my answer?